# JavaFX - RadioButtons in TableCell with Add Data Button

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button, tableview

I'm currently working on an application where I use a `TableView` including `RadioButton`s in one `TableCell`. For that I created an own `RadioButtonCell` class. I also have a "Add new Row"-Button to let the user add some additional rows. After clicking the "Add" button a third time, I get more `RadioButtonCell`s than rows. I don't find the mistake in my code.

Here a screenshot after clicking the `Button` a third time:

[image: part of the tableview]

RadioButtonCell:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class RadioButtonCell<S,T extends Enum<T>> extends TableCell<S,T>{

    private EnumSet<T> enumeration;

    public RadioButtonCell(EnumSet<T> enumeration) {
        this.enumeration = enumeration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) 
        {
            // GUI
            HBox hb = new HBox(7);
            hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

            // create a radio button for each 'element' of the enumeration
            for (Enum<T> enumElement : enumeration) {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(enumElement.toString());
                radioButton.setUserData(enumElement);
                radioButton.setToggleGroup(group);
                hb.getChildren().add(radioButton);
                if (enumElement.equals(item)) {
                    radioButton.setSelected(true);
                }
            }

            // issue events on change of the selected radio button
            group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable,
                        Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
                    getTableView().edit(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                    RadioButtonCell.this.commitEdit((T) newValue.getUserData());
                }
            });
            setGraphic(hb);
        } 
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Points {

    private final SimpleObjectProperty<Participation> participation = new SimpleObjectProperty<Participation>(); // radio buttons


    public static enum Participation {
        NONE, HALO, BORDER;

        public String toString() {
            return super.toString().toLowerCase();
        };
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param <Participation>
     */
    public Points(Participation p) {

        this.participation.setValue(p);

    public void setParticipation(Participation p){
        participation.set(p);
    }

    public Participation getParticipation(){
        return participation.get();
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Participation> ParticipationProperty() {
        return participation;
    }
}
```

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1250.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="address.view.DataOverviewController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="splitPaneVertical" prefHeight="776.0" prefWidth="1200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <items>
            <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" stylesheets="@Theme.css">
               <tabs>
                  <Tab text="Points">
                     <content>
                        <SplitPane fx:id="splitPaneHorizontal" dividerPositions="0.949874686716792" orientation="VERTICAL" stylesheets="@Theme.css">
                          <items>
                              <TableView fx:id="pointsDataTable">
                                <columns>                                
                                  <TableColumn fx:id="pointsBackgroundColumn" prefWidth="200.0" resizable="false" text="Background" />                                 
                                </columns>                                            
                              </TableView>
                            <AnchorPane SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false">
                                 <children>
                                    <HBox fx:id="pointsHBoxButton" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="1016.0" spacing="20.0" stylesheets="@Theme.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                       <children>
                                          <Button fx:id="pointsAddButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddPoints" text="Add" />                     
                                     </children>
                                </HBox>
                             </children>
                          </AnchorPane>
                       </items>
                    </SplitPane>
                 </content>
              </Tab>
           </tabs>
        </TabPane>
     </items>
  </SplitPane>
```

Controller:

```
    public class DataOverviewController {
        @FXML
        private TableView<Points> pointsDataTable;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Points, Participation> pointsBackgroundColumn;

        @FXML
        private Button pointsButtonAdd;

        public DataOverviewController() {
        }

        @FXML
        private void initialize() {
            // select multipe rows, make rows editable
            pointsDataTable.setEditable(true);
            pointsDataTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
            linesDataTable.setEditable(true);

             pointsBackgroundColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new RadioButtonCell<Points, Participation>(EnumSet.allOf(Participation.class)));
             pointsBackgroundColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Points, Participation>("Participation"));
             pointsBackgroundColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Points, Participation>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Points, Participation> t) {
                                ((Points) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                                    ).setParticipation(t.getNewValue());
                            }
                        }
                    );

        public void setMainConfig(MainConfig mainConfig) {
            // Add observable list data to the table
            pointsDataTable.setItems(mainConfig.getTableDataPoints());
        }

        @FXML
        private void handleAddPoints() {
            // create new record and add it to the tableview
            Points dataPoints = new Points(0, "Points", "TabFileName.tab",Participation.NONE, false, false, 18, "new");
            pointsDataTable.getItems().add(dataPoints);
        }
    }
}
```

I reduced my code to the important parts. Maybe someone can help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items can be added as well as removed from `TableCell`s. This means you need to handle the case where the `TableCell` becomes empty by undoing any changes done to the cell when a item was added. Otherwise there may be `TableCell`s that look as if they contain a item although they are actually empty.

A `updateItem` method should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        // modifications to restore the empty state
    } else {
        // customized way of displaying the item
    }
}
```

Furthermore I do not recommend recreating the `Node`s for displaying the item in the cell every time the item is changed, since this means you'll have a lot of unnecessary node creations which is the thing `TableView` is trying to avoid by reusing cells. Store them in fields and keep them for later use instead.